# Kramdown extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jekyll, kramdown

Kramdown has this cool Table of Content generation with

```
{: .toc}
```

This generate a nice TOC such as in order/unorder list in html as :

```
<ul id="markdown-toc">
   <li></li>
   ...
</ul>
```

But sometime i want to control more on it like to use Bootstrap `List Group` or even use `<div>` markup then the `<ul><li></li></ul>`.

Is there a way to inherit/override this `toc` module to generate my own markup?

Note: I used github pages with jekyll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not — the `{: toc}` syntax doesn't accept any modifications other than through `toc_levels` (which allows your to specify the `toc` depth; see [the options documentation](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/options.html) for details). Essentially you can specify [whether you'd like the list to be unordered or ordered](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/converter/html.html#toc) depending on whether you use

```
* Table of contents
{: toc}
```

or

```
1. Table of contents
{: toc}
```

You can also exclude headers by using the `{: .no_toc}` option (at least if you're using `auto-ids`, since as only headers with ids are added, if you are not using that option you can also just not provide an id):

```
# Header
{: .no_toc}
```

Anything else you have to do with CSS, Javascript, or postprocessing. However, that's often relatively straightforward as you can wrap the entire `toc` in a `<div>` if you wish or add whatever class you want to the `<ul>`/`<ol>` enclosing the `toc`. If you're having trouble getting the `toc` to generate within your `div`, make sure you're allowing for [block level parsing](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#html-blocks) either with `parse_block_html` globally or `markdown="block"` options on the table of contents itself. For example,

```
# Header

<div markdown="block" id="xyzzy">
* TOC
{: toc .class}
</div>
```

should generate

```
<h1 id="header">Header</h1>

<div id="xyzzy">
<ul class="class" id="markdown-toc">
  <li><a href="#header" id="markdown-toc-header">Header</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```